# Change Java soap service result element name

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap

I'm trying to write simple java soap web service ,for that purpose download eclipse and create dynamic web application,in that project create this class and method:

```
package test;
public class Sayam{
    public String helloworld(){
         return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

on that class right click and choose web service and generate web service,every thing is ok and web service return this result:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapnv:Body>
    <helloWorldResponse>
       <helloWorldReturn>Hello World!</helloWorldReturn>
    </helloWorldResponse>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</soapnv:Body>
```

i want change this line:

```
<helloWorldReturn>Hello World!</helloWorldReturn>
```

to my custome element:

```
<QueryResult>Hello World!</QueryResult>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be aware of final contract's names, it's no matter. Any client should use any *"wsdl to code"* (codegen) tool.

You and your service clients should not treat directly with the XML layer (of the most general SOAP protocol).

If you are the webservice owner, you can define it as *"code first"* (you define your classes and methods and the platform update the WSDL definition for you).

If you aren't the owner, you should demand the contract (the WSDL) and use any codegen (**wsimport** is a typical one).

If you are trying to define a webservice for certain XML format and you have the XSD definition or whatelse, **do not try to create a SOAP service**, instead, treat that layer (the XML data) directly (using the proper tools of course like the standard specification for *Java* **JAXB**).

If anyway, you want to change that word, you have some options:

1. write the WSDL yourself (manually or using some tool) and then, create the webservice (eg. using **wsimport**).
2. search if you platform is able to do this (jaxws is not without hacking)

Comment: thanks for pay attention my question,i'm web service owner and in client document says:you must return your value in <QueryResult> element

Comment: _"you must return"_ then you aren't the service owner, you should implement the client specifications (and the client is the owner of that protocol). Then, you should define your own WSDL if **really** it's a requirement.

Comment: (are you sure you cannot get the specified WSDL? that is, not exists?)